# Powerapps and azure pipeline triggers

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powerapps

Using Powerapps, I'm writing a canvas app.
I would not want to Trigger an Azure pipeline when I click Save or publish as I may only do these things at the end of the day for example - not when I'm ready to put it into a branch.
The only time I would want to trigger the pipeline is when I export the package.
Is it possible to set the export of the package as the pipeline trigger?

One possibility may be to queue a build in logic apps.

[image]